# Unable to fetch annotated vales from JAR File

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

annoted class  shown below present inside MySample project

```
@Description(name = "foo", description = "bar")
public class Test {

    //////

}
```

Fetching vales from jar in below code

```
File file  = new File("MySample.jar");
    URL url = file.toURL();  
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.example.Test");
    Description annotations = cls.getClass().getAnnotation(Description.class);

    // annotations instance is null
```

Because of annotations instance null i am not able to fetch vales.

Does any one have idea how to solve this problem or any other alternatives ?

Comment: Are you sure that @Description in your 'Test' class and Description.class are of the same class by fully-qualified name?

Comment: Both are same class

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure `Description` has `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.

If you already have this, what happens is that two different classloaders are loading the `Description` class. The first one is the `URLClassLoader` you created (`cl`), the second your normal application classloader. When you call `getAnnotation(Description.class)` you ask the class loaded by `cl` for an annotation class loaded by the app. loader, and since the classes are identified by their loader, those two are effectively entirely different classes, so the comparison fails and you get no result.

Now, the question is why are you loading this jar in this convoluted way in the first place? Why do you need your own classloader instance?

If you tried something like: `ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader()` this would probably work. But it would only make sense if the jar id added to the classpath at runtime.

Otherwise, `Test.class.getAnnotation(Description.class)` (no classloader business) would make much more sense.